# How to handle errors using Google Drive API in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-drive-api

I am using

```yaml
googleapis: ^11.4.0
googleapis_auth: ^1.4.1
```

The API is:

```dart
var result = await driveApi.files.create(
    driveFile,
    uploadMedia: media,
);
```

How to handle errors? Like network connectivity problems.

The method has signature:

```dart
  async.Future<File> create( ... )
```

But the docs say:

```dart
  ///
  /// Completes with a [File].
  ///
  /// Completes with a [commons.ApiRequestError] if the API endpoint returned an
  /// error.
  ///
```

Comment: wrap result statement in try catch?

Comment: I agree wirh @Clevino Alrin. In general, you can use error handling methods like try catch. Can you please share a sample code to replicate the error you encountered? You can also add the specific error that you encountered so that other community members may further look into the issues you encountered.

Comment: For connectivity problems, you will have to add a check before result statement like if (!connectionAvailable) return showSnackBar('no internet');